# Copy-Paste from Mac to Emacs of ubuntu

Tags: macos, copy-paste, unix, emacs

I use `version 10.9.2 of OS X` and a virtual machine `6.0.5 VMware Fusion`. `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` has been installed on the virtual machine. In ubuntu I use `Emacs 24.3.1` as editor.

Once emacs of ubuntu is launched, the `Kill Menu` (see `Edit` -> `Paste from Kill Menu`) is empty. If I want to copy a text from Chrome under Mac to Emacs under ubuntu, I can use `Command+C` (which saves the text into the Kill Menu of Emacs) then `Command+V` or `Ctrl+V`.

I can also copy and paste a text within Emacs by using `Command+C` (which also saves the text into the Kill Menu of Emacs) then `Command+V` or `Ctrl+V`.

However, the problem is, after I copy and paste something within Emacs, I could not copy and paste a test from Mac to Emacs anymore by `Command+C` then `Command+V` or `Ctrl+V`: `Command+C` under a Chrome page of Mac can not save the text into the Kill Menu anymore. Consequently, `Command+V` or `Ctrl+V` within Emacs always pastes the last element in the Kill Menu, which is not what I want.

So I have to close and re-launch Emacs to clean the Kill Menu to enable the copy-paste from Mac to Emacs of ubuntu, which is tedious...

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues here. One is how to copy from Mac to Ubuntu. That is the work of the VM. You have to set it up and oftentimes it depends on capturing the mouse/keyboard (you may want to look it up in your vmware config for the specific VM you are using, I mean, the one running Ubuntu). From what you said, it looks like this part is working ok.

Then there is a question about the Kill-Yank ring in Emacs. Usually, you kill (cut) using `Command+K` (it kills from the cursor position to the end of the current line; you can kill characters with `Control+K` or words with `Option(alt)+K`) and you paste with `Command+Y` (it will paste everything that you had killed just before yanking it up). So, unless it is somehow configured differently, whatever you copy or cut with `Command+C` or `Command+X` on your Mac side (provided it is correctly configured on VMWare) should be available on Emacs by using `Command+Y` not `Command+V`.

Hope it helps.

P.S. There is also another trick: Ubuntu tends to think of the mouse as a peripheral having three buttons. Selecting something (just selecting, not copying or cutting it) and pressing the middle button normally pastes it at the cursor position (I don't know, nevertheless, how your VMWare-hosted Ubuntu would differentiate your middle button. Sometimes, it means pressing both buttons at once. On some configurations, you will need to press a modifier (`Option`?) while you click the secondary button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my mac doesn't work that way, but it did allow to to find the solution `Option+Alt+K` (See http://askubuntu.com/a/568012/15432)